# Show $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f$ be continuous on $\Bbb{R}$ and let $\lim_\limits{x\to \infty}f(x)-ax=\lim_\limits{x\to -\infty}f(x)-ax=0$ where $a\in \Bbb{R}$. Show $f$ is uniformly continuous. I did have an attempt but it has some flaws in it. The only thing that is still okay, I suppose, is that, looking at first at $[0,\infty)$, there is $M\in \Bbb{R}$ such that $\forall x>M, |f(x)-ax|<{\epsilon\over 2}$ (Or something like that.) It also includes saying that $f$ is uniformly continuous at $[0,M]$. I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Just like your idea, you can break up the real line into two parts: One a compact interval of the form $[-y,y]$ and the other part the rest of the real line. A continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous, and if you choose $y$ large enough then your function will always be within $\epsilon/3 > 0$ of $ax$ on the second subset, so you can use uniform continuity of the function $ax$ on the second subset, again with the value $\epsilon / 3$. Then use the triangle inequality to get that the values of the function are within $\epsilon$. The only thing that makes this look a little shady is that you keep choosing larger and larger $y$ as $\epsilon \to 0$, so your compact intervals are getting larger and larger, but this is still fine because all you have to say is that you can find SOME $\delta > 0$ that works for a particular $\epsilon > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've made a good start.

I'm pretty rusty, so this is an exercise for me as much as you, and what follows may be too messy. *Caveat emptor!*

That said, my suggestion would be to carry on with the division into two cases that you have started with, but modify it slightly, as follows:

You've got your $M$, depending on some arbitrarily given $\epsilon$. So you can explicitly calculate, in terms of $\epsilon$ and $a$, a $\delta_1 > 0$ such that if $|x|$, $|y|$ are both $> M$, and $|x - y| < \delta_1$, then $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$.

Now you need only worry if one or other of $|x|$, $|y|$ is $\leqslant M$. So, instead of $[0, M]$ or $[-M, M]$, consider $[-M - \delta_1, M + \delta_1]$; and now you need only worry if *both*  $|x|$, $|y|$ are $\leqslant M + \delta_1$.

But you've already taken care of that case, essentially, so you can finish the proof from there.

In more detail:

Choose $M > 0$ so that $|f(x) - ax| < \epsilon/4$ whenever $|x| > M$.

(I think I usually stick all these "$\cdots/4$", "$\cdots/2$" bits in *after* writing more of the proof. Anyway, that's what I'm doing now.)

If $|x| > M$ and $|y| > M$, then $||f(x) - f(y)| - |ax - ay|| \leqslant |(f(x) - f(y)) - (ax - ay)| < \epsilon/2$, so $|f(x) - f(y)| < |a|\cdot|x - y| + \epsilon/2$.

You'll need to judge whether to write that part of the argument out in more *or* less gory detail than I've just done, because - presumably (I don't have much experience of handing in formal work!) - different instructors vary in what they expect.

So if we chose $\delta_1 > 0$ so that $|a| \cdot \delta_1 \leqslant \epsilon/2$ (careful what you write, in case $a = 0$!), then we have  $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$ whenever $|x| > M$ and $|y| > M$ and $|x - y| < \delta_1$.

Now choose $\delta_2 > 0$ so that $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$ whenever $|x| \leqslant M + \delta_1$ and $|y| \leqslant M + \delta_1$ and $|x - y| < \delta_2$. You can do this, because the interval $[-M - \delta_1, M + \delta_1]$ is compact.

(I don't know if you'll be expected to use that particular terminology, but you know about uniform continuity on bounded closed intervals.)

But for any $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|x - y| < \delta_1$, we have either (i) $|x| > M$ and $|y| > M$, or else (ii) $|x| \leqslant M + \delta_1$ and $|y| \leqslant M + \delta_1$.

(Prove it! Don't just take it as obvious. But the obviousness of it helps with constructing the proof.)

And now we're practically done. Take $\delta = \min\{\delta_1, \delta_2\}$, and write your conclusion.

Comment: Thank you too. I do know what you are suggesting, but the fact is that I still get nowhere.

Comment: OK, I'll expand my answer (I hope I don't find errors!) - after breakfast! (Embarrassed cough - it's after midday here.)